# Spring Boot: JSON Deserialization not working for getters/setters

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

**EDIT**:

I created a simple ObjectMapper and told it to map the json to the object.  It threw an error of jackson deserialize

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field

that the application apparently was swallowing and then continuing on.  I know have to fix why my fieldnames are all being given lowercase first letters.

**END EDIT**

I am using Spring Boot, and I am sending an object over the wire in JSON format from a remote application.  I inspect the "packet", I see that all of the objects have NULL where their data should be.  The fields are all private, but are accessible through getters and setters.

I tried creating a dummy DTO object and sending that.  There, I saw that the deserialization worked properly and the fields were correctly set when all the accessors were labeled private.

How do I instruct Jackson in Spring Boot to find the corresponding Getter of the field and to use that to set the property?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is a picture of the object I am trying to send, as well as the dummy DTO object.[image]

[image]

Here is the top of my Rest Controller and the method that's being called.

[image]

And finally, here is a snippet from the troublesome class that isn't being serialized, it's of the @Entity variety.

[image]

Comment: I've never had that not work out of the box. Can you provide some code?

Comment: @CollinD I've added some photos of the classes, hope that helps.

Comment: For future reference, never post screenshots of your code when you can simply copy-paste. Go read [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it was failing was two-fold.  First, I had properties on the sender side that weren't mapped to the deserialization target object on the Java side.  Secondly, when NewtonSofts JSON converter converts stuff, it makes the following transformation "String Name => String name".  This lead to another error where the Jackson converter couldn't find ANY of the destination values in the JSON string.

The solution was to modify my application.properties file with these values:

spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false
spring.jackson.mapper.accept_case_insensitive_properties=true